# Integration (Surface Area)

Tags: integration

This is the question --> [image: http://puu.sh/lWalu/343b3706e3.png]

---

What I have done

$$ S = 2π \int_a^b  f(x)\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2} dx$$

$as$ $$ f(x) = x^3 + {1\over 12x} $$

$therefore$ $$ f'(x) = 3x^2 - {1\over 12x^2}$$

$$ [f'(x)]^2 = {1\over 144x^4} + 9x^4 - {1\over 2} $$

Setting up the integral

$$ Volume = 2π \int_1^3  (x^3 + {1\over 12x}) \sqrt{{1\over 144x^4} + 9x^4 +{1\over 2} } dx $$

How do I go solving this integral or did i go wrong somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this *special case*, in
$$ 
 [f'(x)]^2 = \bigl( 3x^2 - {1\over 12x^2} \bigr)^2 = {1\over 144x^4} + 9x^4 - {1\over 2} 
$$
the "mixed term" from the square is $-1/2$.
Adding $1$ makes that $+1/2$ which can be written as a similar square:
$$
1 + [f'(x)]^2 = {1\over 144x^4} + 9x^4 + {1\over 2} = \bigl( 3x^2 + {1\over 12x^2} \bigr)^2
$$

This simplifies the integral considerably.

Comment: How did you recognize that immediately? Usually with these questions which include heavy algebra , I have trouble recognizing perfect squares , difference of squares etc ...

Comment: @dydxx: I started with the assumption that $1 + f'(x)^2$ can be written as a square, because otherwise the integral would be very difficult to solve. The rest is "experience": The term $-1/2$ in $f'(x)^2$ is the "mixed term", changing that to $+1/2$ gives a similar square.

Comment: @dydxx. When you face this kind of problem, there is a trick. The talent is to find it ....just as Martin did !